# Need to add text to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, text, jpanel, jlabel

So I'm trying to create this really basic calculator that can calculate volume and area. I already have formulas and everything worked out, I just need to get the actual window and text to work. My code just to create the window is here:

```
JFrame myCalc = new JFrame("Area/Volume Calculator");

JTextField input;

myCalc.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

myCalc.setSize(400, 500);
myCalc.setVisible(true);

JLabel welcome = new JLabel("");
welcome.setText("Please choose which shape's area/volume you would like to calculate.");
```

All I need to know is why the JLabel "welcome" isn't actually showing up in the window. The actual window does appear, with the correct title, but there is no text. Keep in mind that I am a beginner at Java and am really only beginning to use Swing.

Thank you!

P.S. I also have no idea how to use the text editor. I understand that the code is badly formatted and that it appears to be missing a class and main method, but it wouldn't let me copy/paste that in.

Comment: myCalc.add(welcome);

Comment: You have created  the JLabel and never use it so either welcome gets thrown to the GC or those two lines are just optimized out as "not doing anything"

Comment: JFrame is like a canvas where you need to add the components like JTextField and JLabel.  So after creating the JFrame use JFrame's add method to add new components as BoDidely suggested

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Another tip:  Create and add components to the frame, **then `pack()` the frame,** then call `frame.setVisible(true)`.

Comment: *"..it wouldn't let me copy/paste that in."* O_o

Answer (score 4):

You will need to add `welcome` to `myCalc`.

Try this:

```
JLabel welcome = new JLabel("Please choose which shape's area/volume you would like to calculate.");
myCalc.add(welcome);

myCalc.pack();
myCalc.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I guess I'll do a little research and update it... Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 0):

**1**. Put this to the end of the your code. Now you will just have to style components in JFrame.

```
   myCalc.setSize(400, 500); //or just myCalc.pack();
   myCalc.getContentPane().add(input);
   myCalc.getContentPane().add(welcome);
   myCalc.setVisible(true);
```

**2.** Here you can find some examples, which will help you get stared with java swing. Here is the link:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/